# Repeated Measures in Mixed Model - Creating Graphics

Tags: mixed-model, repeated-measures, sas

In learning about mixed modeling and how to perform this in SAS I came across this article

https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/sas/seminars/sas-repeatedmeasures/

However, I am not able to wrap my head around how I can tailor the graphics they presented for my purposes. I am trying to predict weight gain of subjects with fixed effects including baseline weight. How do I go from this "group" presentation to illustrating the effect for all participants.

Thanks for any direction, I understand my question may be lacking in many aspects.